# Apache unable to startup, ScriptAlias on Windows

Tags: php, windows, apache

I've installed Apache 2.2 on a Windows machine for use in PHP local coding & debugging. Apache is not running however, says running 0 of 1 services.

When I try to restart it it just says "requested operation failed".

The output from the Test configuration says ScriptAlias takes arguments, a fakename and a realname. The actual lines in the script causing the problem -

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
ScriptAlias /php/ ""
Action application/x-httpd-php "php-cgi.exe"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Look in the apache error log, you should see a more useful error message in there. Are you saying that you still see the `It Works!` page even though the service is not running? If this is the case, you already have an instance of Apache running somewhere - check in Task Manager to see if you can see any `httpd.exe` processes running. The second argument to `ScriptAlias` should be a full file system path, e.g. `C:\program files\apache software foundation\apacha 2.2\cgi-bin`

Comment: Just changed the question. The It works! was a leftover in the browser cache, apologies.

Comment: What does `C:\program files\apache software foundation\apache 2.2\logs\error.log` say when you try and start the service? (might be in `C:\program files (x86)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure port 80 is free, programs like Skype or IIS use it.
XAMPP has a tool for knowing if all ports required are free.